# How do use Ubuntu/Windows to capture video from input?

Tags: video, io, vhs

My Panasonic DMR EZ48 VHS/DVD player has an HDMI output.

I want to copy VHS to digital files on my laptop.

I have a USB to HDMI converter. How do I use my laptop to capture video from the VCR? I am more used  to outputting video from the computer, not inputting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Plug RCA video output (the yellow ones) in VCR with easycap RCA to usb videoConverter. Then stream the video with dvgrab or vlc. 
https://opensource.com/life/15/6/VHS-conversion-MP4-Linux

Comment: I used AVS Video Recorder